# php manual for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

php manual for eclipse

I've downloaded eclipse for php - Eclipse PDT 3.0.x All In Ones - at "http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/" and added php manual chm file.

Click [here](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/"this text appears when you mouse over")!

But still the php function manual not appeared at eclipse with shift+f2 or the context menu.

Please let me know how to enable context help.

Comment: as far as I can see, manuals can be added via URL - http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/php_manual.htm

Comment: @WindStory Can you open the CHM file by double-clicking in Windows Explorer without any problems?
Did you follow the next attention?
>If you are using Windows XP SP2 or later and you are going to download the documentation in CHM format, you need to "unblock" the file after downloading it
(at http://www.php.net/download-docs.php)
What do you mean by "not appeared"?

Comment: atlanto/ I am using windows 7 x64, and chm file is opening well at explorer. But I could not find "unblock" button at peroperty, even though "security".

Comment: sgibly/ I tried "click Open PHP Manual -or- press Shift + F2", but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "Open PHP Manual" (Shift-F2) only works for PHP **functions** in the manual (e.g. "ini_set()", "error_log()"). For **language constructs** it fails silently (e.g. "echo", "isset", "empty"). There is a pending eclipse bug on this ([#269222](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269222)).

You can also display the list of all PHP functions read from the manual site(s) via the "PHP functions" view (Window | Show View | PHP functions).

According to the PDT PHP Manual Integration documentation, the PHP manuals are configured via the PHP Manual Preferences page (`Window | Preferences | PHP | PHP Manual Preferences`). CHM files, remote site URLs or local directories can be used.

In my setup, the English online PHP manual site URL (http://www.php.net/manual/en) was configured by default, so I did not need to change anything.

If it still does not work and you also get no functions displayed in the "PHP functions" view, your project configuration files might be damaged - check the answers to [Eclipse PDT + Code completion not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263590/eclipse-pdt-code-completion-not-working-at-all).