# Eclipse PDT + Code completion not working at all

Tags: php, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt

I wanted to start a new Zend project, and currently I'm facing some issues regarding Eclipse PDT... My problem is, that the code completion in Eclipse for PHP does not work at all.

I tried a lot of different tutorials etc, for example making a new project and import the files; making a new workspace and import projects there; almost every possible combination of buildpath settings and library imports; deleting several files in .metadata (you will find lots of tutorials like this if you google for it), but nothing worked.

[Edit] Also the PHPNature is set (thanks to tranisstor):

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
</natures>
```

(It also does not work if there is only the PHPNature set, and no other in addition)

[/Edit]

The problem in detail: I made a new Zend project, and tried to start coding in the IndexController.indexAction(). First thing I did: I typed in `$this->`, but no code completion came... I thought maybe I would need to add the Zend library, which I did. When I click into the `Zend_Controller_Action` in `class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action` I can see the documentation of `Zend_Controller_Action`, I also can press <kbd>F3</kbd> and the corrosponding file will appear... Which means, Zend is successfully added as library.
I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, but just nothing happens. By the way, the standard PHP functions like `isset()` also won't show up in code completion

Does anybody have a idea how to fix this? I am using Eclipse Juno, with Eclipse PDT 3, and Zend Framework 1.x (don't know exactly, but it's not ZF2 and it works well if I open `http://localhost`.

I'm grateful for any help

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem when upgrading eclipse to Kepler. The following worked for me:

Remove files under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2

The reason was that the workspace old DLTK index is not compliant with the new version and needs to be rebuilt. Start eclipse and the DLTK index will be regenerated.

Code completion worked for me again after that.

Comment: confirm. The same situation - after updating to Kepler code completnion stopped working

Comment: You'd think they'd have fixed it by now, fresh install: same problem. Thanks for the fix

Comment: Same situation here; this fixed worked. It also helps to know that the term is "Code Assist" and then a search reveals http://stackoverflow.com/a/17408431

Comment: Been searching for days, using "code assist" didn't help me find the answer, this finally fixed the issue :)

Comment: Same problem, and same fix, updating PDT on Eclipse Luna SR2. Thanks

Comment: Same problem, fix no longer working, updating PDT on Eclipse Neon.

Answer (score 4):

i feel you, i had to deal with this quite often too, and the mentioned ***.project*** file modifications didn't do the trick.
What helped me was this:

edit the ***.buildpath*** file and add

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

My complete build file might then look sth. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

i also added my folder which contains the php files to the build and include path (RMB over the project), but i don't think that it was necessary, the most important part was the modification of the .buildpath file for me.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hey Larzan and thank you for your response. This was also something I tried first, but it also did not help... At the moment I am running two Eclipse versions, Eclipse for Java Developers and Eclipse for PHP Developers. On the PHP-Dev-version it works, but it sucks anyway to maintain two instances of Eclipse (updates, settings, etc... I must do everything twice...)

Comment: Adding the `buildpathentry` did the trick for me. This is on a fresh (non-upgraded) version of Kepler SR1.

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution (at [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/489559/1065653/#msg_1065653)) didn't work for me. What fixed this problem was the following:

1. going to Properties for my project (right click on it in PHP Explorer, then Properties),
2. select PHP Build Path/"Add Folder"
3. in there I ticked/selected my project's main folder.

It took a while while the DLTK database was refreshed (it could block your machine for a couple of minutes, be patient) but then it started working great.

Answer (score 1):

Remove workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/*. It should works.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way:

Right click on you project in the project Explorer » Configure » Add PHP support...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to edit your .project-File and add a "PHP nature" tag. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177569/why-does-eclipse-code-completion-not-work-on-some-projects) for more information. I once had this issue after putting a project under svn version control and it seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Thanks but in Eclipse it's visible as PHP project. The PHPNature tag is set. Like I said, I tried everything what you can find in google :/

Answer (score 0):

I've found a sollution on [eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489641/). Downgrading to PDT 3.1.2 solved the problem.

Regards, 
Marek

Answer (score 0):

After trying the other possible solutions on this page, I managed to get code completion to work in PDT 3.2 with the latest Dynamic Languages Toolkit in Eclipse Juno.

Juno usually installs DLTK version 4.0 by default so I downloaded DLTK 5.0 from here: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R5.0/R-5.0-201306060709/. Use the **Core Frameworks** > **EMF** > **Runtime Version** link, which downloads a zip file so you will need to do a local install:
In Eclipse select **Help** > **Install New Software** > **Add** > **Archive** > navigate to the zip file > type **DLTK** in the **Name** box and confirm.

Use Eclipse's **Install new software** to get PDT 3.2 from the PDT repository, if it is not already installed: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.2/release

Option 2: Before I tried the previous method I installed PDT 3.1, which I got from the Juno update site (instead of the PDT repository):
**Install New Software** > http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno. Code completion worked in 3.1, so it's another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but involving just one PHP file. Then I found that I was using the following syntax for the initialization of a variable inside a method:

```
$rule = ($fullValidation)?(new StartTimeRule()):(new NullRule());
```

The problem seems to be the use of the inline condition. The code was working but apparently broke some Eclipse features, like the F3 command, autocompletion, the outline view, etc. I could be wrong, but I think this is a bug of the DTLK indexer.

I changed that line with a standard if statement, not an inline condition, and all the features now work again.

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download ZF2 and put it to your perefered Location (~Frameworks/ZF2)
2. Eclipse: Window > Preferences > PHP > Libraries = Push "New"-Button, add a Name
3. choose added Item and click "Add External Folder"-Button. Choose you ZF2 destination
4. Be sure, your Project is "PHP Project" (see: Mark Project-Base-Folder, click Project in Menu > Project Natures and choose PHP Project.
5. This will rebuild your Project, if not also choose Project > build Project.

Now all should work like a charm (on  Kepler Service Release 2)